# Actualizar filas automáticamente que contengan una formula

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, función-personalizada

Estoy necesitando lograr que a través de Google Apps Script, pueda identificar las celdas que estén utilizando una fórmula particular y que cada cierto momento, dicha fila se actualice.

Hoy tengo una función que se llama `=TRAERDATOS()` que pinta en la celda en cuestión algunos datos que obtiene desde una API. Resulta que esa API va cambiando sus datos durante el día y para eso es necesario que la celda que se pinta a través de la función `TRAERDATOS` se actualice constantemente (cada 10 segundos por ejemplo), y al ejecutarse la función dicha celda se pinte con los datos actualizados.

Hasta ahora logré capturar las celdas que contienen esa fórmula, pero lo que necesito ahora es poder actualizarlas cada x tiempo.

¿Cómo es posible hacer eso?

Hasta ahora tengo este código:

```
function ValidarCeldaConPedidoDatos() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numCols = rows.getNumColumns();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var string = "";
  var formula="";

  for (var i = 0; i < numRows; ++i)
  {
    for (var j = 0; j < numCols; j++)
    {
      formula = sheet.getRange(i + 1, j + 1).getFormula().toString();
      if (formula.includes("=TRAERDATOS"))
      {
        //sheet.setCurrentCell(sheet.getRange(i + 1, j + 1))
        sheet.getRange(i + 1, j + 1).setFormula(formula)
        Logger.log("TRAE DATOS | fila: "+i+" | col: "+j+ " | form:" + formula);
      }
    } 
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`TRAERDATOS` es una función personalizada. Este tipo de funciones se recalculan cuando al menos uno de sus parámetros cambia.

Considerando lo anterior podrías agregar un parámetro que sirva para indicar que se debe recalcular, por ejemplo, `=TRAERDATOS(A1)`, entonces sólo tienes que cambiar el valor de A1 para hacer que `TRAERDATOS` se recalcule.

Ya sea que apliques lo anterior o decidas continuar usando tu función que reescribe la formula, para actualizar periódicamente use un activador basado en tiempo (time-driven trigger). Para esto,

1. Abre tu proyecto en el editor de secuencia de comandos
2. En el panel de la izquierda, haz click en Activadores (tiene un ícono de un relog). Esto abrirá la página de activadores del proyecto activo.
3. En la página de activadores del proyecto activo haz clic en **Agregar activador**
4. En el diálogo, selecciona la función a ejecutar, en el tipo de activador selecciona basado en tiempo, y luego los parámetros correspondientes para establecer la frecuencia.