# Copiar un dato entre libros de Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, función-personalizada

Estoy atascado en google sheets... os expongo caso libro1 libro2 ----  quiero copiar un solo dato de libro2 a libro1 en una celda concreta .

Tengo este error:

[image: Error de google spreadsheet]

En el libro1 el script que tengo:

```
function testcopiar()
{

var idhoja = '1ZaSQIa2GAEX11O4hseS1jQTrFYP3c6E7XtNToAkjzNY (IDPAGINA)';
var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wePFnri1nSa6lfipxn5xk3XBB9gztQsVZ9U52fnUlaI/edit?usp=sharing'

return copyTo(url);


}


function copyTo(destinationSSId) {

    let copySheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("HOJA1");
 let pasteSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(destinationSSId).getSheetByName("HOJA2");
    let pasteSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(destinationSSId).getSheetByName("HOJA2");

    let sourceValues = copySheet.getRange("A1").getValue();

  Logger.log(sourceValues);

  return sourceValues;

}
```

He puesto scopes por si era tema de permisos....  en el libro 2 de donde leeré el dato, en el `appscript.JSON`

```
{ "oauthScopes": [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly"
  ],
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}
```

Me devuelve el error al ejecutar la función desde la hoja de calculo:

> Error
> Exception: You do not have permission to call  SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets (línea 18).

Si lo devuelvo en el `Logger.log` no tengo problemas me lo muestra, el problema esta en devolverlo como una función dentro de una celda dentro del libro.

Entiendo que deba haber alguna forma de permisos entre hojas, porque si no con ID seria o URL sería un fallo de seguridad y alguien podría consultar tu libro, pero no entiendo como en tu misma unidad de Drive no se pueda copiar entre libros, acción habitual en una Excel , sin ningún problema, ya que el que gestiona es el propio motor de la capa superior de Excel, que contiene libros, los libros hojas, y las hojas columnas y filas, y ambas celdas, y dentro valores....

No se como puedo hacer esto, y si no se puede porque.

Saludos

Comment: Por favor agrega un [mcve] incluyendo los pasos que sigues para ejecutar el script.

Comment: Ya esta modificado.

Answer (score 0):

Las funciones personalizadas no pueden ejecutar comandos que requieran autorización, como SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.openById y SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.openByUrl. Una opción es usar uno de activadores instalables, "edit", "change" o "time-driven".

Referencias

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

Relacionado

- [Actualizar filas automáticamente que contengan una formula](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/446953/65)